# Notation for random point on an area

Tags: notation, random

Given that $S $ is a surface area.

What is a good notation to indicate that a variable (position)  $x_0$ is set to a random point on $S$.

---

For now my solution is to simply write $x_0 \gets rnd(S)$, but this feels  insufficient.

Comment: Let $x_{0}\in S$ be randomly given.

Comment: @Floris that doesn't specify the distribution. For example, if $S$ is the entire plane, then there isn't a uniform distribution to assume, so it's very important to specify the distribution then.

Comment: In cases I consider $S$ is a bounded area and I want to sample uniformly. Then perhaps the following?

"Let $x_0 \in S$ be randomly and uniformly sampled  from $S$. "
 
Other suggestions/improvements are welcome.